# Spring Batch migration of _seq tables

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm in the process of migrating from spring boot 2 to 3, and I have a specific trouble with Spring Batch.

My source code use this kind of stuff for key generation:

```
@Entity
public class Currency {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
```

In my MySQL database, these tables had been auto generated:

```
| currency                     |
| currency_seq                 |
```

The _seq tables contain the values of primary keys:

```
mysql> select * from currency_seq;
+----------+
| next_val |
+----------+
|       51 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now with Spring Batch 5, something has changed and the values are ignored:

```
ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement [Duplicate entry '1' for key 'currency.PRIMARY'] [insert into currency (currency,currency_change,date,id) values (?,?,?,?)]
```

I've not seen what to do in this [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide).

I use these props:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=ALWAYS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [@SequenceGenerator](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/sequencegenerator):

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "currency_seq", sequenceName = "currency_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "currency_seq")
private Long id;
```

The `allocationSize` with the value greater than `1` shouldn't be used for high-load environment as it has non-volatile effect.